# Laravel throws 404 when $request->validate fails

Tags: php, laravel, rest, validation

We're creating a REST API for our application.

**web.php**

```
Route::post('add-new-student', 'StudentController@addNewStudent');
```

**StudentController.php**

```php
...
function addNewStudent(Request $request)
{
    $validation = $request->validate([
        'student_mobile' => 'required|digits:10',
        'student_name' => 'required|min:3|max:50',
        'student_email' => 'email:rfc|max:50',
    ]);

    if ($validation->fails()) {
        // show error json
    } else {
        // add new student
    }
}
...
```

Now when we send the JSON response, if there is error, instead of going to else block it shows 404 page in postman.

We don't know what we are doing wrong!

**Note**

- Our routes are correct (double checked)
- In postman, we are sending post request

Comment: I believe `$request->validate()` performs a redirect when it fails. What URL is throwing that 404?

Comment: url is same, as we are testing on postman

Comment: Use `$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [...]);` and then you'll can `if ($validator->fails()) { ... }`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ worked thanks!

Answer (score 28):

The Validation Request class checks if your request is an ajax request or a normal request.

If it's a normal request it does: redirect()->back() with the validation messages in the session.

If it's an ajax request it shows a json object with the validation messages in it.

Frontend frameworks/libraries like example jQuery add a header to an ajax request to let the backend know it's an ajax request. Laravel checks this header to decide what to do.

Postman does not automatically send this header. So you should add one of the following headers manually:

```
Accept: application/json

X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: In my case that was the solution. thanks

Comment: thanks, it helps with my laravel 8 form request when u do post api request

Answer (score 3):

The `$request->validate()` performs a redirect when it fails, then the `if($validation->fails())` is never executed.

Correct answer is [Manually Creating Validators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#manually-creating-validators)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator; // include this at top

$validation = Validator::make($request->all() ,[
   'student_mobile'   =>  'required|digits:10',
   'student_name'     =>  'required|min:3|max:50',
   'student_email'    =>  'email:rfc|max:50',
]);

if($validation->fails()) {
   // validation failed
} else {
   // validation passed
}
```